# Qt - Worker thread freezes the UI

Tags: multithreading, qt, symbian, qthread

This is my first experience on threading with Qt, so bear with me.

I have a singleton "system" object which periodically executes a heavy piece of code.
I control the system singleton from my UI, but the system is not aware of the UI.

I create a thread in my main, and then move the system to it:

```
QThread systemThread;

System::instance()->moveToThread(&systemThread);

systemThread.start();
qApp.exec();
```

The UI hangs until the system's periodical processing cycle is complete.

I have also tried to subclass QThread and calling *exec* from the *run* method.

What could be the problem? I'm certainly doing something wrong.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the excellent article about [Threads, Events and QObjects](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects) in the Qt developer wiki. Something seems to be wrong with the thread affinity, you can check that with QObject::thread().

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to follow this guideline from a Qt Developer himself when implementing multithreading: https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

It is way more effective and painless.

Answer (score 0):

`systemThread.start()` will start `systemThread.run()` method in thread so you need to implement it inside `run()`.

To create your own threads, subclass `QThread` and reimplement `run()`.

Comment: I refactored my system to be ran inside the _run_ method, but the UI still hangs if I for example initiate a WLAN scan in the run method.